# Is the Low-Density Supersonic Decelerator scheduled for any upcoming Mars mission? Is the program still active?

Tags: mars, reentry, future-missions, ldsd

Back in 2014 and 2015, some tests of the [Low-Density Supersonic Decelerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-Density_Supersonic_Decelerator) were performed. The LDSD is intended to land heavier payloads on Mars than is currently possible.

Mark Adler (the project manager) [answered a question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8615/8693) back in 2015 about what Mars missions where going to use the LDSD.

The [project page](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/tdm/ldsd/overview.html) states "could be used in Mars missions launching as early as 2020", but I'm having some doubts about that information being up to date as that's the current year.

Is the program still active?

Comment: When Mark Adler [answered a different question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19440/12102) there was no mention of being project manager! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the process of typing out the question, as often happens, I stumbled upon the answer.

[The budget for LDSD was cut in 2016](https://spacenews.com/nasa-cuts-funds-for-mars-landing-technology-work/)

Which explains why things have been very quite since.

Supposedly, efforts may speed up again when we eventually need to land heavy things on Mars.